# How to modify the dynamic range of an image (gray scale) in matlab to be between [-3000 15000]?

Tags: matlab

how can I modify the dynamic range of an image (gray scale [-30000 30000]) in matlab to be between [-3000 15000]?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the second argument of imagesc to do that:

```
imagesc(rand(10),[-3000 15000])
colormap('gray')
```

Comment: +1 I knew there was a function for this, been out of MATLAB world for too long.

Answer (score 1):

Simple interpolation along with some vector multiplication

```
x1 = img[i,j]
O1 = -30000 // min range of values in img
O2 = 30000  // max range of values in img
T1 = -3000  // min range of target value
T2 = 15000  // max range of target value

x2 = ((x1 - O1) * (T2 - T1)) / (O2 - O1) // Value in new range
```

Using the above equation and two passes over the matrix using vectorization you can convert the values.  I leave that part to you.